# Is it normal to run docker instance running tomcat and deploy to this tomcat applications?

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I'm using Docker with `DOCKERFILE` to create basic environment for the applications. This involves installing *os*, *java* and *tomcat*.

I have a question regarding to this - if is it ok to run docker instance with tomcat installed and deploy applications, updated version of the applications to the running docker container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ok as long as you remember that any change to the filesystem will be "lost" when the container exits.

If you want to start a container with the *updated* apps, it would be best to:

- either `docker commit` the running container where the app updates tooks place
- or (best practice), update the Dockerfile with the update steps (in order to be able to reproduce), `docker build` that new image, and start a new container with the right apps at the right versions.

Comment: I mean that I'm NOT stopping the currently RUNNING container, just keep updaing the web-applications in the running container. I found that it's not a bad idea, but I need to clarify this, am I not wrong with that approach? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Yuri as long as the container is running, you are not wrong. But the idea of a container is to run from a fixed reproducible state frozen in an image built from a Dockerfile. And that is not what you are doing. If you re-run your container from the same image, you would not find all the updates that you are doing.

Comment: Yes, that's ok in my case. I'm planning to do this manually at some point in the future.